# I can not convert my accelerometer data xyz into frequency

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, frequency, accelerometer

I am using Arduino nano ble 33, and I want to covert accelerometer values which are x,y,z into frequencies then these frequencies values need to be sent through the Arduino nano 33 ble. Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code: The code now only reads the raw data from the accelerometer.

```
< #include "Arduino.h"
    #include <ArduinoBLE.h>
    #include "Nano33BLEAccelerometer.h"
    // #include "arduinoFFT.h"
    
    #define BLE_BUFFER_SIZES    20
    #define BLE_DEVICE_NAME     "Nano 33 BLE"
    #define BLE_LOCAL_NAME      "Accelerometer BLE"
    
    
    Nano33BLEAccelerometerData accelerometerData;
    
    BLEService BLEAccelerometer("590d65c7-3a0a-4023-a05a-6aaf2f22441c");
    BLECharacteristic accelerometerXBLE("0004", BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast, 
    BLE_BUFFER_SIZES);
    BLECharacteristic accelerometerYBLE("0005", BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast, BLE_BUFFER_SIZES);
    BLECharacteristic accelerometerZBLE("0006", BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast, BLE_BUFFER_SIZES);
    
    
    char bleBuffer[BLE_BUFFER_SIZES];
    
    void setup()
    {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        while(!Serial);
    
        if (!BLE.begin()) 
        {
            while (1);    
        }
        else
        {
            BLE.setDeviceName(BLE_DEVICE_NAME);
            BLE.setLocalName(BLE_LOCAL_NAME);
            BLE.setAdvertisedService(BLEAccelerometer);
    
            BLEAccelerometer.addCharacteristic(accelerometerXBLE);
            BLEAccelerometer.addCharacteristic(accelerometerYBLE);
            BLEAccelerometer.addCharacteristic(accelerometerZBLE);
    
            BLE.addService(BLEAccelerometer);
            BLE.advertise();
    
            Accelerometer.begin();
            accelerometerXBLE.writeValue((byte)0x01);
            
            accelerometerYBLE.writeValue((byte)0x01);
            accelerometerZBLE.writeValue((byte)0x01); 
            Serial.println("X, Y, Z");
        }
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
        BLEDevice central = BLE.central();
        if(central)
        {
          Serial.println("Connected");
            int writeLength;
            while(central.connected())
            {            
                if(Accelerometer.pop(accelerometerData))
                {
                    writeLength = sprintf(bleBuffer, "%f", accelerometerData.x);
                    accelerometerXBLE.writeValue(bleBuffer);
                    writeLength = sprintf(bleBuffer, "%f", accelerometerData.y);
                    accelerometerYBLE.writeValue(bleBuffer);
                    writeLength = sprintf(bleBuffer, "%f", accelerometerData.z);
                    accelerometerZBLE.writeValue(bleBuffer);      
                    delay(1000);
                    Serial.printf("%f,%f,%f\r\n", accelerometerData.x, accelerometerData.y, 
                     accelerometerData.z);
                }
            }
        }
    } >
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not simple. You will need to use a Fourier transformation. Read about it here: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/chap8.pdf